# Following c# code doesn't display the certificates present in local machine

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HasPrivateKey { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        var stores = new Dictionary<StoreName, string>()
        {
            { StoreName.My,"Personal"},
            { StoreName.Root,"Trusted roots"},
            { StoreName.TrustedPublisher,"Trusted Publishers"}
        }.Select(s => new { store = new X509Store(s.Key, StoreLocation.LocalMachine), Location = s.Value }).ToArray();
        foreach (var store in stores)
            store.store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var list = stores.SelectMany(s => s.store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().Select(mCert => new Form1
        {
            HasPrivateKey = mCert.HasPrivateKey ? "Yes" : "No",
            Name = mCert.FriendlyName,
            Location = s.Location,
            Issuer = mCert.Issuer
        })).ToList();


    }
}
```

I have used windows form application in c#.
If I click the button it has to display the available certificates present in local machine onto listbox. But I don't know how to display the available certificates.. Pls give suggestions.

Comment: It will vary based on certificate present in certificate store in local machine

Answer (score 1):

1. You create a new Form1 instance for each certificate.
2. You do not refer to any existing listbox

try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    //declare new listbox
    ListBox lbCerts;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //add a listbox to the form
        lbCerts = new ListBox();
        lbCerts.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.Controls.Add(lbCerts);
    }

    //class represent certificate
    class myCer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string HasPrivateKey { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Issuer { get; set; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stores = new Dictionary<StoreName, string>()
            {
                { StoreName.My,"Personal"},
                { StoreName.Root,"Trusted roots"},
                { StoreName.TrustedPublisher,"Trusted Publishers"}
            }.Select(s => new { store = new X509Store(s.Key, StoreLocation.LocalMachine), Location = s.Value }).ToArray();
        foreach (var store in stores)
            store.store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        //create list of myCer
        var list = stores.SelectMany(s => s.store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().Select(mCert => new myCer
        {
            HasPrivateKey = mCert.HasPrivateKey ? "Yes" : "No",
            Name = mCert.FriendlyName,
            Location = s.Location,
            Issuer = mCert.Issuer
        })).ToList();
        //populate listbox
        lbCerts.DataSource = list;

    }
 }
```